# Define step amount in foreach loop for python3

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

In Python 3, working on a foreach loop. The problem is I want to skip every X items. Is there a way to define the step value? I know for a regular for loop you can just say `for x in range(0,10,2)` but I do not believe that's possible in a foreach.

Comment: You could use range and index the list like `a[x] `

Comment: You can just use list slicing: a[::2], where 2 is the 'step'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default for loop in python is, in fact, a foreach loop, it can only iterate over objects. Python doesn't have loops like `for(i=0;i<n;i++)`. Range is an iterable object, same as lists and tuples, etc. As you've already mentioned, you can set steps when defining ranges, but if you want to set steps with other iterable objects, you may use slices

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for item in my_list[::2]:
    print(item, end=' ')  # output: 1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice
for x in islice(lst, 0, None, step):
    print(x)
```

This skips `step - 1` items.